# emails getting sent with wrong "from" address

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix/dovecot system setup on Ubuntu 10.04, and it sends/receives emails fine, but when I send emails they are all from root@mydomain.com.

For example, I have a user called "info" and when I try to send an email using mutt from this Mailbox "/home/vmail/mydomain.com/info/Maildir" the email will send find but it will be from "root@mydomain.com" and not "info@mydomain.com". I have 3 mailboxes (/home/vmail/mydomain.com/root/Maildir, /home/vmail/mydomain.com/root/postmaster, and /home/vmail/mydomain.com/root/info) and they all send and receive emails.

I am new to postfix and dovecot... can someone who knows what they are doing help me out on this one??

```
 30 myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
 31 alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
 32 alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
 33 myorigin = mydomain.com #have tried setting myorigin = mail.mydomain.com and still same problem
 34 mydestination = mail.mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
 35 relayhost =
 36 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
 37 mailbox_size_limit = 0
 38 recipient_delimiter = +
 39 inet_interfaces = all
 40 html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
 41 message_size_limit = 30720000
 42 virtual_alias_domains =
```

This is from the aliases file

```
 postmaster: root
 root: postmaster@mydomain.com
```

Comment: What user are you logged in as when you are using Mutt?

Comment: I am logged in as root. I guess this is not an error, and just how mutt is programmed? I thought if I was in a users mailbox the from header would be for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following two settings in your `.muttrc`:

```
realname="info"
from="info@mydomain.com"
```

You can also edit the headers of a message before sending by using `E` (that is the default on my machine, check with `?`). This will open the whole message in your editor and you can fiddle with the headers to your heart's content.

UPDATE:

Sorry I should just say, if you want these settings to only be asserted when accessing certain mailboxes, you need some accounts/folder hooks. You'll need to adapt these to your situation (as these are munged from my own .muttrc for my imap access):

```
account-hook imaps://<dovecot domain>/ 'set imap_user="info"'
folder-hook imaps://<dovecot domain>/ 'set folder="imaps://<dovecot domain>" record="+Sent"  postponed="+Drafts" from="info@mydomain.com" realname="info"'
```